# Python telebot как отправлять рандомные фотки указывая при этом только папку с фото

Tags: python, telebot, случайные-числа

Возможно ли сделать, чтобы бот отправлял рандомные фотографии с папки и при не перечислять все ссылки на фото как в данном коде? указать папку в которой содержаться фото

```html
  mem = [
     "https://sun9-g.jpg",
     "https://sun9-g.jpg",
     "https://sun9-g.jpg"         
          ]
     bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, random.choice(mem))
```

Comment: да, возможно...

Comment: И что у вас все ссылки отправляются юзеру?

Comment: Нет рандомные, но как избавиться от такой писанины,если мне надо будет 100 фоток, мне что 100 ссылок писать?

Answer (score 0):

Да, конечно, с помощью модуля OS

```
import os
    
directory = 'C:\\python' #директория, обязательно разделяйте путь с помощью //
files = os.listdir(directory) #получение списка файлов
print(files) #вывод файлов(для проверки работы)
```